# Combinatorics- 6 digits decreasing code

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I need to find out how many combinations can you use to make a code sequence like this :
All digits are 0-9 and they can't increase
For example: 887665 is a valid combination.
I tried putting  a monotonic hard increasing sequence and then subtract it from $ 10^6 $ but I can't figure out how many combinations there are for increasing sequences, only that if we start at 4 there is only 1 combination.
$ \begin{pmatrix}0&1&2&3&4&5\\ 1&2&3&4&5&6\\ 2&3&4&5&6&7\\ 3&4&5&6&7&8\\ 4&5&6&7&8&9\end{pmatrix} $

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for the number of tuples $(x_1,\dots,x_6)$ such that $$9\geq x_1\geq\dots\geq x_6\geq 0.$$
We can see this as the number of ways to split $6$ balls into $10$ bins, which is $\binom{6+10-1}{6}=5005$.

---

Alternatively, add $6$ to the first digit, $5$ to the second, and so on down to $1$ for the last. This transforms your number into a six-element subset of $\{1,\dots,15\}$. Further, given any subset of $\{1,\dots,15\}$ with size $6$, we can reverse this process to get a $6$ digit number with non-increasing digits. So the answer is just $\binom{15}{6}$.

---

A third method: count the number of paths from $(0,9)$ to $(6,0)$, where you are only allowed to move one step right or down at a time. What is the connection to the original problem?

Comment: Mind explaining why is $ 9\geq x_1\geq\dots\geq x_6\geq 0. $ the same as splitting 6 balls into 10 bins? We have the restriction that there are more balls in the left bin and so on..

Comment: The balls are the digits, and the bins are the values $0,\dots,9$. Say, e.g., you have one ball in bin $3$, two in bin $4$, two in bin $7$ and one in bin $9$. What six-digit number does this correspond to?